# Get XML element by tag name

Tags: php, xml

`var_dump($object)` outputs the following result:

```
object(stdClass)#9 (5) {
    ["data"]=>  object(stdClass)#8 {
        ["validFiling"]=>  object(stdClass)#7 {
                ["indicators"]=>  string(6) "MODE_S"
        }
        ["plan"]=>  object(stdClass)#6 {
            ["id"]=>  string(10) "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

In this data structure I need to access the content of the field `id`. I do this in the following way:

```
try
{
  $object =   $client->getPlan($p);
  var_dump($object);
}
  catch (Exception $e) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}

$line = $client->getLastResponse();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($line);
$data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('data');
$fp = $data->getElementsByTagName('plan');
$id = $fp->getElementsByTagName('id');
$fId = $id->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

And the error is (at the line `$fp = $data->getElementsByTagName('plan')`):

```
Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Proper indentation/debug output is your friend. Note the formatting change to your object dump. That makes the access chain MUCH clearer. As well;, `$data` is a DOMNodeList object. It does NOT have a getElementsByTagName() method. You need to access the individual nodes within that object and then do the gEBTN() on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `$data` is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which doesn't have the `getElementsByTagName()` method. You have the same problem with the `$fp` variable. If you want to access the first `data` element found, then change to:

```
$data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('data')->item(0);
$fp = $data->getElementsByTagName('plan')->item(0);
$id = $fp->getElementsByTagName('id');
```

Or if you want to iterate of the `data` elements and apply the processing to each:

```
$dataList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('data');

foreach($dataList as $data)
{
    $fp = $data->getElementsByTagName('plan')->item(0);
    $id = $fp->getElementsByTagName('id');
    $fId = $id->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

The above works because its calling `getElementsByTagName()` on the node itself not the list.